# qsort did not sort the array of string

Tags: c

I tried to sort an array of string using qsort. here is the content of my array:

```
{"a","orange","apple","mobile","car"}
```

this is how I use qsort:

```
int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
  const char *pa = (const char*)a;
  const char *pb = (const char*)b;
  return strcmp(pa,pb);
}

int stringLen = sizeof(input)/sizeof(char *);
qsort(input, stringLen, sizeof (char*), myCompare);
```

However, when I print the array, nothing is changed. is there something wrong w/ this?

Comment: What is input declared as?

Comment: char **input = (char **)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char*));

Comment: there's your problem!

Comment: an array of pointers to char, is not the same as a contiguous memory block of char of the same size.

Comment: @MitchWheat what do you mean? I can't use stringLen? so what should I do? even if I put an array of string {"aaa","vvv","abc","mmm"} it still output the same thing

Comment: Last try: please post all the relevant ACTUAL code.

Answer (score 10):

I've changed your myCompare function to what Mitch Wheat had posted earlier, and that works properly. Here's the example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
    const char *pa = *(const char**)a;
    const char *pb = *(const char**)b;

    return strcmp(pa,pb);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    const char *input[] = {"a","orange","apple","mobile","car"};

    int stringLen = sizeof(input) / sizeof(char *);
    qsort(input, stringLen, sizeof(char *), myCompare);

    for (i=0; i<stringLen; ++i)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, input[i]);
}
```

This will return:

```
0: a
1: apple
2: car
3: mobile
4: orange
```

Comment: I just copy paste ur code, but it doesn't work T.T is it possible that something is wrong w/ the compiler?

Comment: No. As I said some time ago: it's how you declare your 'array'. THE COMPILER ISN"T BROKEN! Point of diminishing return reached....

Comment: @MitchWheat but according to sharth it works properly

Comment: It also works correctly here: http://ideone.com/UqvehY

Comment: To keep const qualifier between castings, these lines must change a little:
const char * pa = *(const char * const * ) a;
const char * pb = *(const char * const * ) b;

Answer (score 4):

`qsort(input, stringLen, sizeof (char*), myCompare)` calls `myCompare` to compare strings which are sorted.

`myCompare` gets **pointers to compared values**. In our case we get pointers to strings (`const char**`). So we should compare `*(const char**)a` and `*(const char**)b`, which are strings pointed by `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Start debugging with:

```
int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
  const char *pa = (const char*)a;
  const char *pb = (const char*)b;

  printf("Comparing %s vs. %s for result %d\n", pa, pb, strcmp(pa,pb));

  return strcmp(pa,pb);
}
```

I think shortly after that, you'll figure out the problem. :)

Comment: nothing is wrong. it return a correct value for every a and b